# How to remove slider from Django-admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Yesterday I tried to upgrade all my pip packages and after that, I have got a problem with this slider. Whenever I try to open or create an instance of some model it appears. I have tried to roll back packages. Delete python and reinstall it. Tried to create a new project, but it seems the problem is in admin templates. [Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR3lr.png)

#### Python:

Python 3.9.7

#### pip freeze:

```
appdirs==1.4.4
asgiref==3.4.0
autopep8==1.5.7
certifi==2021.5.30
cffi==1.14.6
charset-normalizer==2.0.4
cryptography==3.4.8
defusedxml==0.7.1
distlib==0.3.2
Django==3.2.5
django-allauth==0.45.0
django-cors-headers==3.8.0
django-rest-auth==0.9.5
djangorestframework==3.12.4
filelock==3.0.12
idna==3.2
mysqlclient @ file:///D:/Stol/GitHub/smotors/mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
oauthlib==3.1.1
Pillow==8.3.1
psycopg2==2.9.1
pycodestyle==2.7.0
pycparser==2.20
PyJWT==2.1.0
python3-openid==3.2.0
pytz==2021.1
requests==2.26.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
toml==0.10.2
urllib3==1.26.6
virtualenv==20.4.7
```

Comment: Have you tried running `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: @hashlash Thank you for answering. The problem was that i have installed Python 3.9 and had previous version of Django 3.2.5. When I update Django to 3.7 and mysqlclient to 2.0.3 all problems are gone. Thank you for reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Python 3.6 with Django 3.2.7 and mysqlclient 1.4.6. So when I updated Python to 3.9 I had problems with sql cursor and django-admin templates. Everything you need to do is just update all packages. This slider seems to be new feature of django-admin or maybe I am blind and did not see it before